# Prove in newton's method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, proof-explanation

I have to prove,  that  the  direction  in  Newton's  method  is  a  descent  direction  if  the Hessian is positive defnite.

My idea:

$ direction = -H(x)^{-1}*\nabla f(x)$

Put how can I prove that this is a descent direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a vector $p$ is a descent direction if $$ \nabla f(x) \cdot p <0.$$
Now, since $\nabla^2f(x)$ is positive definite, $\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}$ is also positive definite and therefore $$ \forall y, \; \; \; \nabla^2f(x)^{-1}y\cdot y>0.$$
We can then deduce that $$\nabla f(x) \cdot (-\nabla^2f(x) ^{-1} \nabla f(x)) =  - (\nabla^2f(x)^{-1} \nabla f(x)) \cdot \nabla  f(x)<0$$
which means that this is indeed a descent direction.